# Moving a git server: should I make repos bare?

Tags: git

I'm pulling a bunch of company git repositories from an older host to our company git server. I started by just `git clone`-ing the old repos into the repositories directory on the new server. Soon we're going to point DNS for the old host to the new server.

My question is this: should I make the new repositories bare repos before this switch happens, or can they function as they are (normal, non-bare repositories with `.git/` directories)? I'm guessing the former, but I'd like someone who actually knows to confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like voretaq7 said.  Yes, it is highly advisable.

In [GitMagic ch3](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch03.html) there is a good explanation of why you want to
use a bare repo.

> A bare repository is so named because it has no working directory; it
>   only contains files that are normally hidden away in the .git
>   subdirectory. In other words, it maintains the history of a project,
>   and never holds a snapshot of any given version.
>
> A bare repository plays a role similar to that of the main server in a
>   centralized version control system: the home of your project.
>   Developers clone your project from it, and push the latest official
>   changes to it. Typically it resides on a server that does little else
>   but disseminate data. Development occurs in the clones, so the home
>   repository can do without a working directory.

To make the transition easy use:

```
git clone --mirror
```

There is question on StackOverflow that discusses the [the difference between git clone --mirror and git clone --bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare).

Comment: Two good answers, thanks. You get the reputation for adding references and background.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *have* to make them bare repositories, but I would strongly consider doing so for the sake of cosmetic consistency (git "servers" have a bare repo, git "clients" have a checkout with a .git directory).

If nothing else, it's less to back up.